# How to install a specific Chart version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install a previous version of Prometheus, namely version `6.7.4`:

```
helm install -f stable/prometheus/values.yaml prometheus --name stable/prometheus --namespace prometheus --version 6.7.4
```

However it installs the latest version, `prometheus-6.8.0`:

```
$ helm ls
NAME        REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART               NAMESPACE 
prometheus  1           Fri Jul  6 01:46:42 2018    DEPLOYED    prometheus-6.8.0    prometheus
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `--version 6.7.4` should do the trick. is it possible run the command from a working directory that had a copy of the latest chart? (the way you point to values files suggest you have the chart locally)

Answer (score 40):

Below worked for me with **Helm-3**:

**Step-1 :** `helm search repo mongo -l`

*( Assuming you have already done `helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami`)*

**Step-2 :** Check the mongo version you want to install and note the corresponding latest chart version

**Step-3 :** Use the chart version from above to install the specific version of mongoDB using --version.

`helm install my-mongodb bitnami/mongodb --version 8.3.1`

**Note :** *8.3.1 is the chart version not mongoDB version*

Comment: Did not work for me, I had to add quotes like --version "8.3.1" for it to pull the correct version of the chart.

Answer (score 21):

I see in the [`helm install` code](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/4adead9cc641176f54b12afb6e18f5dccbf923c3/scripts/get#L177-L183):

```
# help provides possible cli installation arguments
help () {
  echo "Accepted cli arguments are:"
  echo -e "\t[--help|-h ] ->> prints this help"
  echo -e "\t[--version|-v <desired_version>] . When not defined it defaults to latest"
  echo -e "\te.g. --version v2.4.0  or -v latest"
}
```

So just in case, do try with: `--version v6.7.4` instead of `--version 6.7.4`.

Comment: Good idea but still doesn't work. Ran `helm del --purge prometheus`. `helm ls` correctly returns an empty list. Then `helm install --version v6.7.4 --namespace prometheus  --name prometheus stable/prometheus`. `helm ls` returns again `prometheus-6.8.0`. I can confirms from k8s dashboard that 6.8.0 was installed.

Comment: @MasterScrat: were you able to resolve this issue.. I am also running into same issue so asking.. I tried helm delete --purge command and then helm install, but no help

Comment: @lucky no I never figured it out

Comment: this is out of the script that installs helm itself. the question is about installing a specific version of a helm chart.

Answer (score 19):

I think your command is wrong:

```
helm install -f stable/prometheus/values.yaml prometheus --name stable/prometheus --namespace prometheus --version 6.7.4
```

Helm install command is:

```
helm install [CHART] [flags]
```

So in your case this should be:

```
helm install prometheus stable/prometheus -f stable/prometheus/values.yaml  --namespace prometheus
```

-- version is used for chart versions:

```
  --version string           Specify the exact chart version to use. If this is not specified, the latest version is used
```

Above command will install Prometheus version that is specified in values.yaml under `tag` but read this: `https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus` for full list of parameters.

Answer (score 12):

Use `--version "0.15.0"` i.e. the version number in double quotes. It worked for me.

Comment: Same, for me it worked with quotes and without the quotes it did not work.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't see an accepted answer and of course arrived here via Google and Reddit, so posting here.

Confirmed working:

```
➜ helm install argocd argo/argo-cd --version="1.6.2" -f argocd-helm-values.yaml -n argocd
...
➜ helm list --all-namespaces
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
argocd  argocd      1           2020-08-22 16:35:37.516098 +0700 +07    deployed    argo-cd-1.6.2   1.3.6
```

It seems the placement of `--version` matters. Placing it after the `-n` (namespace) caused an error. However placing it before/after the `-f` worked fine.

Quotes didn't matter, both the commands below worked fine:

```
➜ helm install argocd argo/argo-cd -f argocd-helm-values.yaml --version=1.6.2 -n argocd
➜ helm install argocd argo/argo-cd --version="1.6.2" -f argocd-helm-values.yaml -n argocd
```

Finally, it seems that the equal sign is optional. Both the commands below also worked:

```
➜ helm install argocd argo/argo-cd -f argocd-helm-values.yaml --version=1.6.2 -n argocd
➜ helm install argocd argo/argo-cd -f argocd-helm-values.yaml --version 1.6.2 -n argocd
```

TL;DR

```
helm install <RELEASE_NAME> <REPO>/<CHART> --version <VERSION>

eg.
helm install my_release repo/app --version 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the RCA however faced the same issue and it looks like it happens only when we use --version flag to specify the version. I used the path to chart directory which was created by downloading the chart pkg and exploding and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

First Upgrade your tiller

```
helm init --service-account tiller --wait --upgrade
```

Then in `--version flag` *use chart version relevant to prometheus version which you are trying to install*.

**Eg:** `helm install stable/prometheus --namespace monitoring --name prometheus --version=8.5.0`

Here I *tried to install 2.6.1 prometheus version*.