# Helm: How to pin version & make it manageable by Renovate on GitHub

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, kubernetes-helm, traefik, renovate

Currently we [install Traefik using Helm as described in the docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/install-traefik/#use-the-helm-chart) from it's chart at https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart. This

> ... chart bootstraps Traefik version 2 as a Kubernetes ingress controller, using Custom Resources IngressRoute: https://docs.traefik.io/providers/kubernetes-crd/

We do all this right inside our GitHub Actions workflow [provision.yml](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/blob/main/.github/workflows/provision.yml):

```yaml
      - name: Install Traefik via Helm
        run: |
          echo "--- Install Traefik via Helm (which is already installed in GitHub Actions environment https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments)
          helm repo add traefik https://helm.traefik.io/traefik
          helm repo update
          helm upgrade -i traefik traefik/traefik
```

Instead of `helm install traefik traefik/traefik` we use `helm upgrade -i traefik traefik/traefik` to prevent the error `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot re-use a name that is still in use`(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70465191/4964553).

But now we want to integrate our setup with Renovate. [Renovate supports helm](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/helm-values/), but we don't have a `values.yaml` file or a Helm chart ourselves - we only use one to install Traefik. So how can we pin the Traefik version and make this repo manageable by Renovate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only using `--version` ([as described in this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200917/how-to-install-a-specific-chart-version)) isn't enough for us, [since Renovate needs a dependency file to look at](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/helm-values/).

But [there's another way](https://mjpitz.com/blog/2020/12/03/renovate-your-gitops/) to use a simple `Chart.yaml` to pin our version and have a manageble file for Renovate (here's [the `Chart.yaml` from the example project on GitHub](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/blob/main/traefik/install/Chart.yaml)):

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
type: application
name: traefik
version: 0.0.0 # unused
appVersion: 0.0.0 # unused
dependencies:
  - name: traefik
    repository: https://helm.traefik.io/traefik
    version: 10.19.4
```

Now with the commands (the `.` means, that the `Chart.yaml` is in the same directory as we run our commands):

```
helm dependency update .
helm upgrade -i traefik .
```

we can now install Traefik in a Renovate-ready way.

The next time a new Traefik helm chart version got released, Renovate should pick up it's work:

[image]